# APEX Creating Dynamic List of Values in a tabular form

Tags: oracle-apex, lov

I have a query similar to :

```
SELECT empno, empname, deptno
FROM EMP
```

in a tabular form, where `deptno` is a SELECT LIST containing all of the records in DEPT. I'm trying to use `empno` in a sub-select within the LOV query in order to limit the number of DEPT records returned.

How do I reference EMPNO from a tabular form withing an LOV query?

Comment: Is one EMPNO associated with multiple DEPTNO?

Comment: Not easy to do - see http://www.deneskubicek.blogspot.co.uk/2008_04_01_archive.html

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use `APEX_ITEM.SELECT_LIST_FROM_QUERY` in some form for column #3. You'll need to set it to Standard Report Column. Your query will look something like:

```
SELECT empno, empname,
       apex_item.select_list_from_query(
           p_idx => 3, 
           p_query => 'SELECT dname, deptno FROM dept' ) AS deptno
  FROM emp
```

For the `p_idx` parameter, you need to select something that isn't in use by the tabular form. You might have to check the code that's generated by the tabular form and select a `f0x` index not already in use. The values for the form will come in the `apex_application.g_f0x` array variable.